# Como Hacer que un archivo vbscript presione la tecla CTRL + C?

Tags: vbscript, vbs

necesito hacer que un archivo VBScript presione la tecla CTRL + C solo una vez pero pues no se como solo se que para la tecla C es:

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Sleep 100

WshShell.SendKeys "{C}"

Ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Sleep 100

WshShell.SendKeys "^{C}"
```

Así se hace.
[Aquí](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) hay una web que funciona y te lo explica y te dice como nombrar las teclas.
Pero si no quieres entrar iría así:
Puede estar compuesto por 1 o 2 partes, las teclas y el prefijo . Si fuese una seria así por ejemplo(nada fuere de los corchetes):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```

Y con prefijo(SHIFT, Ctrl y Alt) seria así por ejemplo:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys "^{n}"
```

Se tengo algún error comentarlo o buscar en Google o en la anterior pagina que di

Comment: Sería de ayuda tanto para el OP como para los que vean tu respuesta en el futuro que expliques que hace tu código.